# Issue with bulk insert in mysql using pdo and php

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

I am trying to insert bulk records in mysql using pdo but for some reason I am not able to build up the query.

My  POST looks like this

```
Array
(       
    [ques_1] => dsadasd
    [ques_2] => 5
    [ques_3] => dasdsad
    [ques_4] => 23/7/2014
    [savecontinue] => Save & Continue
)
```

My desired array should look like this

```
Array
(        
    [quid] => 1        
    [answer] => dasdsad
)
Array
(        
    [quid] => 2       
    [answer] => on
)
Array
(       
    [quid] => 3       
    [answer] => dasdsad
)
Array
(        
    [quid] => 4        
    [answer] => 23/7/2014
)
```

My code looks like this

```
foreach($_POST as $k=>$v)
{
    if($k != 'savecontinue' and  $k != 'skipsave')
    {
        list(,$qid) = explode("_",$k);
        $insertData[$qid]  = $v;

    }
}

$sql = "INSERT INTO answers (quid, answer)
        VALUES (:quid, :answer)";
$query = $this->db->prepare($sql);
$query->execute($insertData);
```

The error is  **PDOStatement::execute(): SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens**

**Note:** I have simplified/reduced the query params and code for better understanding.

Comment: I'd var_dump($insertData) to check if it matches the parameters.

Comment: Yes I did and it gives me this Array([4] => 23/7/2014).

Comment: There you go.. $insertData has only 1 key/value where it was supposed to have 5 in order to fulfil the binding. Maybe you meant $insertData[$qid] = $v in the loop?

Comment: Doesn't work, I have simplified the question now.

Comment: As hjpotter mentioned, your logic is flawed. var_dump($_POST) and provide the output in the question.

Comment: You have two choices. Either you change your code to process whatever current $_POST returns or fix the form so that it returns multi-dimensional array you can loop through and insert multiple records.

Comment: Please see @RiggsFolly's code and that works. Anyways thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well it seems to me that you would be better of with something like this.

You also were passing to many parameters to the INSERT, the array you pass must have only those values required by the query and be named with the ':' in front.

```
// prepare the query for multiple use later
$sql = "INSERT INTO answers (userid, catid, quid, qstep, answer)
        VALUES (:userid, :catid, :quid, :qstep, :answer)";
$query = $this->db->prepare($sql);

// create an array of inputs
for ($x=1; $x < 5; $x++ ) {
    $insertData[]  = array( ':userid' => 1,
                            ':catid'  => $_POST['catid'],
                            ':quid'   => $x,
                            ':qstep'  => 1,
                            ':answer' => $_POST['ques_'.$x]);  
}

// loop over the array of inputs 
foreach ( $insertData as $data ) {
    $query->execute($data);
}
```

Comment: This was an answer to the original question before you chnanged it. Is the **original** question the real situation or the **new** question.

Comment: Thanks @RiggsFolly . I changed the original question to make it simple/understandable by the other users.Let me try it.

Comment: Awesome...Brilliant...I have to modify the code a little bit to adjust with other parameters I have. One thing which I am wondering about that is if it is possible not to run the $query->execute($data); inside the foreach loop and rather if we can do $query->execute($insertData);

Comment: Ahh no sorry...we can't do that.Please ignore my last comment.Thank you so much for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Change the following:

```
$insertData  = array("$qid"=>"$v");
```

to:

```
$insertData[$qid] = $v;
```

Comment: @Raj It doesn't work because your loop logic is flawed. Nowhere in your loop are you assigning the values to keys `answer`, `userid` or `quid` etc.

Comment: I have simplified the question/post but still getting --"Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens"